# Is there some sort of way to roll back the initialize_project_db script in pyramid?

Tags: python, database, pyramid

I am a rails developer that is learning python and I am doing a project using the pyramid framework. I am used to having some sort of way of rolling back the database changes If I change the models in some sort of way. Is there some sort of database rollback that works similar to the initialize_project_db command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initialize_db` is not a migration script. It is for bootstrapping your model and that's that. If you want to tie in migrations with upgrade/rollback support, look at `alembic` for SQL schema migrations.